# Why would they beat up Leviim who fell asleep on the job and burn their clothes?

Tags: levites-leviyim, masechet-midot

Middos 1:2 reads (translation from [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Middot.1.2):

> אִישׁ הַר הַבַּיִת הָיָה מְחַזֵּר עַל כָּל מִשְׁמָר וּמִשְׁמָר, וַאֲבוּקוֹת דּוֹלְקִין לְפָנָיו, וְכָל מִשְׁמָר שֶׁאֵינוֹ עוֹמֵד, אוֹמֵר לוֹ אִישׁ הַר הַבַּיִת, שָׁלוֹם עָלֶיךָ. נִכָּר שֶׁהוּא יָשֵׁן, חוֹבְטוֹ בְמַקְלוֹ. וּרְשׁוּת הָיָה לוֹ לִשְׂרֹף אֶת כְּסוּתוֹ. וְהֵם אוֹמְרִים, מַה קּוֹל בָּעֲזָרָה. קוֹל בֶּן לֵוִי לוֹקֶה וּבְגָדָיו נִשְׂרָפִין, שֶׁיָּשֵׁן לוֹ עַל מִשְׁמָרוֹ.
>
> The officer of the Temple Mount used to go round to every watch, with lighted torches before him, and if any watcher did not rise [at his approach] and say to him, “Shalom to you, officer of the Temple Mount," it was obvious that he was asleep. Then he used to beat him with his rod. And he had permission to burn his clothes. And the others would say: What is the noise in the courtyard? It is the cry of a Levite who is being beaten and whose clothes are being burned, because he was asleep at his watch.

This Mishnah is cited in [Tamid 27b-28a](https://www.sefaria.org/https://www.sefaria.org/Tamid.27b.18-28a.2), where the Gemara comments:

> א"ר חייא בר אבא כי מטי רבי יוחנן בהא מתניתא אמר הכי אשריהם לראשונים שאפילו על אונס שינה עושין דין שלא על אונס שינה על אחת כמה וכמה
>
> R' Chiya bar Abba said: "When R' Yochanan would reach this Mishnah, he would say thus: 'Praise unto the early ones, for even on unintentional sleep they would mete out judgement; for sleep which was not unintentional, all the more so!"

This Gemara clearly states that this was intended as a punishment, not an extreme method of waking them up.

Now, as far as I can tell, the obligation to guard the Beis HaMikdash is indeed Biblical, but it's phrased as a positive commandment, as in [Bamidbar 18:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.18.4):

> וְנִלְו֣וּ עָלֶ֔יךָ וְשָֽׁמְר֗וּ אֶת־מִשְׁמֶ֙רֶת֙ אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֔ד לְכֹ֖ל עֲבֹדַ֣ת הָאֹ֑הֶל
>
> And [the Leviim] will be joined onto you [the Kohanim] and guard the guarding of the Tent of Meeting for all the work of the Tent.

As this is a positive commandment, there shouldn't be any corporal punishment for failing to fulfill it. Even if there is a passuk of which I'm unaware which explicitly says they cannot fall asleep on the job, that would make it a negative commandment, where the punishment is 39 lashes by a whip, not beating him with a rod and possibly burning his clothes.

Seemingly, then, this is a Rabbinic institution. Why did they feel the need to institute this, and why in this particular fashion?

Comment: "Even if there is a passuk of which I'm unaware which explicitly says they cannot fall asleep on the job, that would make it a negative commandment" it would probably be a לאו שאין בו מעשה with no human punishment

Comment: @Heshy How is sleeping אין בו מעשה?

Comment: I always assumed it was *pour encourager les autres*

Comment: @Joel Of course, but why was it necessary to do so, and why in this fashion?

Comment: @donielf כבוד המקדש?

Comment: @Joshk was it indeed in the ׳מקדש׳?

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel See Mishnah 1 there; they’re guarding in and around the Mikdash.

Comment: Compared to the Roman punishment of certain death for the same thing, it wasn't so bad.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, the Kohanim were certainly no Somnos, but I can’t think of anything else in Judaism where such a punishment was enacted.

Comment: The background is interesting but the conclusion - "*Seemingly, then, this is a Rabbinic institution*" is questionable. I have a feeling that Beyt Hamikdash was a separate authority, accepting only Kohen Gadol's (and his party Cohanim) rulings. Remember that the Mishnah was written centuries after its fall and it is merely *descriptive* not ruling. So your question boils down to was it legal from the point of OUR Halachah, and was the executor liable for corporal damages?